# how to add email/print in joomla 2.5 custom component

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

Kindly explain me how to add email/print icon in my component (joomla 2.5).

I am able to accomplish it partially but i cannot print plus this is not a standard way i guess. The print icon and email icon is missing.

```
<a href="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_mailto&tmpl=component&&template=shape5_vertex&link=ffc8df4efb9cbf37a836ddfeb67f6d0df4155699'); ?>" title="Email" onclick="window.open(this.href,'win2','width=400,height=350,menubar=yes,resizable=yes'); return false;"><img src="/joomla/media/system/images/emailButton.png" alt="Email"  /></a>
<a href="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_mycomp&view=comps&tmpl=component&print=1'); ?>" title="Print" onclick="window.open(this.href,'win2','status=no,toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,titlebar=no,menubar=no,resizable=yes,width=640,height=480,directories=no,location=no'); return false;" rel="nofollow"><img src="/joomla/media/system/images/printButton.png" alt="Print"  /></a>
```

Comment: Try to remove leading slashes from IMG source.

Comment: no luck bro, nothing happens

Comment: I usually add full URL for images in my extensions. This allows me to avoid possible conflicts on different configurations. So add JURI::root() to the beginning if IMG source and remove leading slash. Should be good.

Comment: Do you have a print template in the root of your component directory?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

In a recent project I used the below Joomla Docs tutorial successfully to add print functionality.

You must construct the your URL like so:

```
<?php
    $isModal = JRequest::getVar( 'print' ) == 1; // 'print=1' will only be present in the url of the modal window, not in the presentation of the page
    if( $isModal) {
            $href = '"#" onclick="window.print(); return false;"';
    } else {
            $href = 'status=no,toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,titlebar=no,menubar=no,resizable=yes,width=640,height=480,directories=no,location=no';
            $href = "window.open(this.href,'win2','".$href."'); return false;";
            $href = '"index.php?option=mycomponent&view=myview&tmpl=component&print=1" '.$href;
    }
?>
    <a href=<?php echo $href; ?> >Click for Printing</a>
```

The same code will render the link in view and in the resulting modal window with the same Click for Printing, except when the user clicks the button in the modal window it will open the browsers print window.

You of course need to adjust the code with relevant component and view information for your project.

http://docs.joomla.org/Adding_print_pop-up_functionality_to_a_component

*** EDIT ***

Be sure to add the following line to the top of the view file:

```
JHtml::_('behavior.modal');
```

*** EDIT 2 ***

I reviewed the sample code and one from a working project I had and noticed one glaring ommission.  I had failed to define the URL parameter for view.  I adjusted the above code snippet (inside else, third $href variable) to reflect change.

Comment: @apaul34208 Lazy phone post on public transportation, post has been edited.  Can I use this as an excuse with my wife to finally purchase a tablet?

Comment: I doubt she would go for it... If she's anything like my wife, she would prefer you to limit your time on SO as much as possible.

Comment: thankyou @BrianBolli ... this is so simple and i did a hell lot of other stuffs like copying the helper class icon.php in com_content and modifying it and the views to make it work.                                                               Well i tried the solution above but I am afraid it does not give me a modal window.

Comment: Forgot one item, see my edit for the line to load modal.js library

Comment: nope JHtml::_('behavior.modal'); do not help. i tried using it both in view as well as in the layout

Comment: I reviewed a working example in a project of mine and noticed a mistake, forgot to declare a view param in URL.  After adjusting try and let me know if that solves it.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i've:

```
<?php $isModal = JRequest::getVar( 'print' ) == 1; // 'print=1' will only be present in the url of the modal window, not in the presentation of the page
    if( $isModal) {
            $href = '"#" onclick="window.print(); return false;"';
    } else {
            $href = 'status=no,toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,titlebar=no,menubar=no,resizable=yes,width=640,height=480,directories=no,location=no';
            $href = "window.open(this.href,'win2','".$href."'); return false;";
            $href = '"index.php?option=com_mycomp&view=comps&tmpl=component&print=1&layout=default&page="'.@ $request->limitstart.'"'.$href;
    }?><a href="<?php echo $href; ?>"><img src="templates/shape5_vertex/images/system/printButton.png" alt="Print" /></a>
```